# Spring Boot test: JavaMailSender properties not loaded

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, spring-boot-test

I have a JUnit5 unit test to test my Spring bean for sendig emails.
I use `spring-boot-starter-parent 2.5.0` and its `spring-boot-starter-mail` as dependencies.

In my `/src/test/resources` directory, I have a `application.properties` file which contains the `spring.mail` properties. When I run my test, the beans are instantiated and autowired, but the properties are not loaded. The `javaMailProperties` inside the `JavaMailSender` class are empty.

I don´t want to use `@SpringBootTest` because Spring would try to setup all autoconfigured
beans which fails for some DB DataSources. But it should work this way. What am I missing? Does The `MailSender` not support autowiring properties?

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class EmailClientTest
{
    @TestConfiguration
    static class EmailClientTestConfiguration
    {
        @Bean
        public MailSender emailSender() {
            return new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public EmailClient emailClient(MailSender emailSender) {
            return new EmailClient(emailSender);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private EmailClient emailClient;

    @Test
    void sendEmail() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should it? You are expecting Spring Boot functionality to kick in without using Spring Boot.

Comment: @M.Deinum so i absolutely need to use @SpringBootTest? I thought it also works without it as long as I specify a TestConfiguration.

Comment: No, `@TestConfiguration` is also a Spring Boot feature (although it will load if because it is indirectly an `@Configuration`). BUt do you really want an integration test instead of unit test, with a mocked `MailSender` instance?

Comment: What I want is an integration test that checks if the configuration of the MailSender is correct. I actually don´t want a fully set up application context. Just a MailSender filled with the properties of the application.properties.